# How to check given input values available or not ? in objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb-query

Here's what I get from `console.log(objects)`:

```
{
    "_id" : "5bb20d7556db6915846da55f",
    "gallary" : {
        "profilepic" : [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]

    }
},
{
    "_id" : "5bb20d7556db6915846da55f",
    "gallary" : {
        "profilepic" : [
            "3",
            "4"
        ]

    }
}
```

I have one input arrays, EX: `let uniqueIDs = ["0","1","10"]`. I have to check `gallary.profilepic` whether given input values available or not? Suppose not available means I have to push one array and return the results.

My Code:

```
let uniqueIDs = ["0","1","10"]
db.Gallary.find()
.forEach(function(objects){
    console.log(objects);
    // Here your JS code has to come
})
```

Expected output:

```
["0", "10"]
```

Comment: Don't use blockquotes for styling. Use blockquotes only when you're quoting something.

Comment: Clan you elaborate yourself a little bit more? I don't understand the relationship between UPIDs and the list of students.

Comment: Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: What do you mean by not available?

Comment: @ Oscar Calderon, UPIDs equal to `regularStudent` values

Comment: @Prasanna everyone has based their answers on your original example. Please don't - two months later - edit your question, and then make edits to _all_ the answers to match too. It makes no sense. Please roll back your question edit.

Comment: But that shouldn't affect the way you implement the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first get all values in DB matching the data you want to enter (otherwise it would load all your collection entries), and then look at missing strings. Finally push a new entry if necessary.

```
const UPIDs = ['0','1','10'];

const entries = await db.Groups.find({
  'members.regularStudent': {
     $in: UPIDs,
  },
});

// Get the strings that are not in the DB
const missing = UPIDs.filter(x => !entries.some(y => y.members.regularStudent.includes(x)));

// Push the missing str in DB
if (missing.length) {
  const obj = new model({
     members: {
        regularStudent: missing,
     },  
  });

  // ...
}
```

---

---

```js
const UPIDs = ['0', '1', '10'];

// Thx to @Andy
const entries = [{"_id":"5bb20d7556db6915846da55f","members":{"regularStudent":['1', '2']}}];

/*
const entries = await db.Groups.find({
  'members.regularStudent': {
     $in: UPIDs,
  },
});
*/

// Get the strings that are not in the DB
const missing = UPIDs.filter(x => !entries.some(y => y.members.regularStudent.includes(x)));

// Push the missing str in DB
if (missing.length) {
  console.log('Add new data for values', missing);
}
```

Comment: I've added an example in snippet

Comment: Because I can't perform mongodb request in stackoverflow... It's for the snippet to work as an example. Whatever you see in stackoverflow, its NEVER made to be copy/pasted. You have to understand what's happening and adapt it to your real case

Answer (score 0):

Filter your `UPIDs` array checking which items of it are not included in the `regularStudent` prop of your `members` data:

```js
let UPIDs = ["0","1","10"];
const data = [{
    "_id" : "5bb20d7556db6915846da55f",
    "members" : {
        "regularStudent" : [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]

    }
},
{
    "_id" : "5bb20d7556db6915846da55f",
    "members" : {
        "regularStudent" : [
            "3",
            "4"
        ]

    }
}];

const regularStudents = data.map(d => d.members.regularStudent).flat();
console.log(UPIDs.filter(a => !regularStudents.includes(a)));
```

Comment: How can i get `data` values, because you are using `data` array, but i am getting objects

Answer (score 0):

You can gather an array of all the IDs together (I've used [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in my example), and then [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out all those elements in UPIDs that don't appear in that array.

```js
const data = [{"_id":"5bb20d7556db6915846da55f","members":{"regularStudent":["1","2"]}},{"_id":"5bb20d7556db6915846da55f","members":{"regularStudent":["3","4"]}}];
const UPIDs = ["0","1","10"];

// Concatenate the ids in the data together
const ids = data.reduce((acc, c) => acc.concat(c.members.regularStudent), []);

// `filter` out the elements in UPIDs that aren't in the ids array
const out = UPIDs.filter(el => !ids.includes(el));

console.log(out);
```

Update for clarification:

Here's your code with mine combined:

```
let UPIDs = ['0', '1', '10'];

db.Groups.find().forEach(function(objects){
  const ids = objects.reduce((acc, c) => acc.concat(c.members.regularStudent), []);
  const out = UPIDs.filter(el => !ids.includes(el));  
  console.log(out);
});
```

Comment: `objects` - as in `console.log(objects)` - is an array of objects I assume or you would not be getting that output.